# Get the amount in two days

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to write a query that will return the amount of sales given the previous day. I am doing a test task for an internship device but have not done this before.

Source table:

| saledate | salesum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | 150 |
| 2022-01-03 | 200 |
| 2022-01-05 | 100 |

Estimated result:

| saledate | salesum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | 250 |
| 2022-01-03 | 350 |
| 2022-01-05 | 300 |

My query:

```
SELECT t1.saledate, t1.salesum=t1.salesum+t2.salesum 
FROM sales t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT saledate, salesum FROM sales 
) t2 
ON t1.saledate=t2.saledate;
```

My result:

| saledate | salesum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | f |
| 2022-01-02 | f |
| 2022-01-03 | f |
| 2022-01-05 | f |

Comment: Mysql <> Postgresql - please re-tag with the correct database

Comment: search for running sum

Comment: Look up `SUM()` in the SQL manual

Comment: And look up WHERE in the SQL Manual

Comment: And ask yourself WHY someone took time to made the question tidy/readable? Then ask why did I mess it up again

Comment: Do you want to accumulate all sales up to Yesterday or Do you want to know only sales made yesterday?

Comment: amount of sales for each day, taking into account the previous day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  saledate
       ,salesum + coalesce(lag(salesum) over(order by saledate),0) as salesum
from    t
```

| saledate | salesum |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | 250 |
| 2022-01-03 | 350 |
| 2022-01-05 | 300 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V5AlPGGV)